# Importing Contracts Pallets - can't find crate for cookie_monster & cake_is_a_lie

Tags: substrate

Trying to solve issue when I run 'cargo check'.

Successfully complied *cargo +nightly-2020-10-06 build*. When I run, cargo check - receive error:
*Rust WASM toolchain not installed, please install it!
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `std`*.

*#![feature(plugin)]
#![plugin(cookie_monster)] // error: can't find crate for `cookie_monster`
extern crate cake_is_a_lie; // error: can't find crate for `cake_is_a_lie`*

I still can not work out where I am going wrong?

Comment: Are you following some tutorial or instructions? Those crate names look like pseudo code... It is probably not meant to actually be used.

Comment: I am following the tutorial... Although when successfully builds cargo, can see pallet-contracts and pallet-contracts-primitives in code window..

Comment: Which tutorial? Can you please share specific links.

Comment: https://substrate.dev/en/tutorials

Comment: I'm working on [contracts pallet] -  https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/add-a-pallet/

Comment: I am not sure where that code would have come from. I agree with Shawn it looks like pseudo code, but I don't believe it comes from the tutorial. The error message should tell you where that code is. Can you try removing it and trying again?

Comment: I am working on Add a Pallet - https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/add-contracts-pallet

Comment: Added new dependencies and code to runtime std feature - then run cargo check, which produced error mentioned.....

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, it compiled successfully using - cargo +nightly-2020-10-06 check.